# Storing result of rename command in a variable

Tags: unix, scripting, rename

I am using following command in unix script to rename files.

```
rename 100 A0 abc100.txt
```

Result of above command is that given filename is changed to:

`abcA0.txt`

I want to store this result (`abcA0.txt`) in a variable within script only so that I can use it for further processing. Is it possible?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the verbose mode and extract the new filename(s).

```
$ var=$(rename -v 100 A0 abc100.txt | sed "s/.*\`\(.*\)'$/\1/")
$ echo "$var"
abcA0.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for inputs, could you please advise what this "sed" command is used for? I didn´t quiet get it.

Comment: I understand, we are passing stream output from "rename" command to "sed" which then somehow takes out substring with the replaced filename to pass to the variable. It works!